# Limit an input to one word

Tags: python-3.x

So here's my code:

```
sentence=input('Please input a sentence: ').lower()
word=input('What word would you like to select? ').lower()
words=sentence.split()
for (A, keyword) in enumerate(words):
    if(keyword==word):
        print(A+1)
if(keyword!=word):
        print ('This word is not in the sentence')
```

I need to limit the users input to only one word and return an error message if they input 2 words, how would i go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the length of the split input is greater than 1:

```
word = input('What word would you like to select? ').lower()
if len(word.split()) > 1:
    raise Exception("Input must be a single word")
```

Comment: I would prefer something like `ValueError`, `Exception` is too broad